# Kinect2 raw depth to distance in meters

Tags: kinect

How to convert the Kinect2 raw depthdata to the distance in meters. The raw depthdata was got by Windows Kinect2 SDK. It's all Integral data.
Point: It's kinect2 rather than kinect1.
I already got the equation of Kinect1,but it's not match.
So anyone can help me.
The equation of Kinect1:

```
if (depthValue < 2047) 
{
  depthM = 1.0 / (depthValue*-0.0030711016 + 3.3309495161);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Kinect API Overview (2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn782033.aspx#ID4E1EAC) indicates:

> The DepthFrame Class represents a frame where each pixel represents the distance of the closest object seen by that pixel. The data for this frame is stored as 16-bit unsigned integers, where each value represents the distance in millimeters. The maximum depth distance is 8 meters, although reliability starts to degrade at around 4.5 meters. Developers can use the depth frame to build custom tracking algorithms in cases where the BodyFrame Class isn’t enough.

Also [V. Pterneas](http://pterneas.com/2014/02/20/kinect-for-windows-version-2-color-depth-and-infrared-streams/) comments in his blog that the values are in meters, he refers to [this code](https://github.com/LightBuzz/Vitruvius/blob/master/Kinect%20v2/WPF/LightBuzz.Vitruvius/Bitmaps/DepthBitmapGenerator.cs#L114). So you could retrieve it from the [`DepthFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.depthframe.aspx) in C# (extracted partially from [this code](https://github.com/LightBuzz/Vitruvius/blob/master/Kinect%20v2/WPF/LightBuzz.Vitruvius/Bitmaps/DepthBitmapGenerator.cs#L114)):

```cs
public override void Update(DepthFrame frame)
{
    ushort minDepth = frame.DepthMinReliableDistance;
    ushort maxDepth = frame.DepthMaxReliableDistance;
    //..
    Width = frame.FrameDescription.Width;
    Height = frame.FrameDescription.Height;
    public ushort[] DepthData;
    //...
    frame.CopyFrameDataToArray(DepthData);
    // now Depthdata contains the depth
}
```

The minimum and maximum depth are given by the functions [`DepthMinReliableDistance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.depthframe.depthminreliabledistance.aspx) and [`DepthMaxReliableDistance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.depthframe.depthmaxreliabledistance.aspx), also in millimeters.